# How to add an XML attribute to an element in Go?

Tags: xml, go, struct, marshalling

I am using the encoding/xml package in Go and the [Encoder example code](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#example_Encoder).

While I am able to produce workable XML, I am unable to add all of the attributes that I need.

As an example, let us use the concept of temperature reporting. What I need is something like this:

```
<environment>
  <temperature type="float" units="c">-11.3</temperature>
</environment>
```

My struct looks like this:

```
type climate struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name    `xml:"environment"`
    Temperature string      `xml:"temperature"`
    Type        string      `xml:"type,attr"`
    Units       string      `xml:"unit,attr"`
}
```

What I end up with looks like this:

```
<environment type="float" unit="c">
  <temperature>-11.3</temperature>
</environment>
```

[My example code in the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/O2fhThftuI)

How can I format the struct tags to put the attributes in the proper element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your desired XML has 2 elements: `<environment>` and `<temperature>`, so you should have 2 types (structs) to model them. And you may use the tag `",chardata"` to tell the encoder to write the field's value as character data and not as an XML element.

```
type environment struct {
    Temperature temperature `xml:"temperature"`
}

type temperature struct {
    Temperature string `xml:",chardata"`
    Type        string `xml:"type,attr"`
    Units       string `xml:"unit,attr"`
}
```

Testing it:

```
x := &environment{
    Temperature: temperature{Temperature: "-11.3", Type: "float", Units: "c"},
}

enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
enc.Indent("", "  ")
if err := enc.Encode(x); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
}
```

It produces the desired output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oicKa9U38K)):

```
<environment>
  <temperature type="float" unit="c">-11.3</temperature>
</environment>
```

Note that you get the same result if you use the `",innerxml"` tag which tells the encoder to write the value verbatim, not subject to the usual marshaling procedure:

```
type temperature struct {
    Temperature string `xml:",innerxml"`
    Type        string `xml:"type,attr"`
    Units       string `xml:"unit,attr"`
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lWQlohI3RT).